# kernel not upgrading to minor versions in 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, kernel, 22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (upgraded from 20.04 LTS). It seems my kernel is not upgraded automatically to newer minor versions:

```
root:~# dpkg uname -a 
Linux destop 5.15.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 07:51:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root:~# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic                 5.15.0-47.51                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-25-generic        5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

altough there is newer version in the [repo already (5.15.0-48)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic)
Also I can find it:

```
root:~# apt search linux-image-5.15.0-48
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-48.54 amd64
  Signed kernel image generic

linux-image-5.15.0-48-lowlatency/jammy-updates,jammy-security 5.15.0-48.54 amd64
  Signed kernel image lowlatency
```

I don't want to upgrade to a newer versions (like 5.19), just the minor one. I would just assume standard
`apt update && apt ugprade` would upgrade the kernel automatically
Is my ssumption wrong? Or is there something misconfigured in my system?
Thanks

EDIT:
output of the `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
root:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://sk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` fixed the issue [as suggested on reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/xoja3w/kernel_not_upgrading_to_minor_versions_in_2204_lts/)